# read: Connection reset by peer using sshfs to connect to AWS

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, sshfs, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to use sshfs to mount a directory on an AWS instance from Ubuntu 16.04.

The command I am using:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=keyfile.pem ec2-user@ecX-X-X-X.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www sshfs/
```

Result (with -o sshfs_debug)

```
SSHFS version 2.5
read: Connection reset by peer
```

`/var/log/secure` entry on AWS instance after attempting to connect:

```
May 10 00:00:33 ip-X-X-X-X sshd[19114]: Connection closed by X.X.X.X [preauth]
```

I tested with a different VPS I run personally and I am able to use sshfs fine, and I have no issues using ssh regularly into this server.

The instance was created using `amzn-ami-hvm-2015.09.0.x86_64-gp2 (ami-cd3aff89)`

Answer (score 5):

I had to use some additional debugging flags to identify the problem, as just `-o sshfs_debug` didn't cut it:

```
-o sshfs_debug -o debug -o LogLevel=DEBUG3
```

This led me to the very verbose ouput that finally got me what I needed to know to solve my problem. The IdentityFile switch does not work out of the current directory, and I had to supply the entire path to the file thusly:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=/home/anna/keyfile.pem ec2-user@ecX-X-X-X.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www sshfs/
```

Comment: I figured it out while looking at a bunch of similar stuff that did not have my problem but I already did all that typing so please enjoy and I hope this helps someone!